# Возможно ли средствами css отобразить фото по размеру квадрата?

Tags: css3, css

Возможно ли средствами css отобразить фото по размеру квадрата?

Comment: я так понял, чтобы картинка была полностью квадратной? 300px на 300px?

Comment: @Vasile, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  max-width: 300px;
}
div figure {
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* 300px/300px = 1 */
  display: block;
  background: url("https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure></figure>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8m71qb16/)

Comment: пожалуйста старайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Не используйте только лишь ссылки на сторонние ресурсы в качестве ответа. Ссылки на сторонние ресурсы имеют свойство "умирать" со временем.

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо сделать изображение фоном к контейнеру квадратной формы:

```css
div.square {
  width: 300px;
  /* ширина картинки */
  height: 300px;
  /* высота картинки */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" style="background-image: url(_путь_к_вашему_изображению_);"></div>
```

Примерно как **[здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/netcrox/hkr54bvs/)**

Answer (score 1):

В css3 есть background-size если ему задать значение cover, изображение будет масштабироваться с сохранением пропорций таким образом, чтобы картинка целиком поместилась внутрь блока.
Ну и картинку делаем background'ом